# Vimeo Embed Not Obeying max-height

Tags: html, css, vimeo, vimeo-player

I have a mysterious problem trying to get a responsive Vimeo embed to work with my overall sight design. What I'm trying to achieve is for the Vimeo embed to render the same as images below it;

HTML:

```
<div class="vimeo"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/180293809?h=9f21a250ca" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div><script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
.vimeo {
  display: block;
  padding: 1vw;
  position:relative;
  max-width: 95vw;
  max-height: 72vh;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

The above renders the div with a height of 0 px. However, when I do the same thing with for example an image, it works just fine. I've also tried to apply the same CSS to the inner iframe, but then it instead just makes the iframe larger while rendering the video player the size of a postage stamp.

Comment: How is the browser supposed to know how high to render anything, if the height of the div will depend on its content, and the height of the content is in turn set as a percentage of the div height? _"However, when I do the same thing with for example an image, it works just fine."_ - an image has intrinsic dimensions, the iframe does not.

Comment: Ah, now that you mention it, that makes sense. Any suggestion on how to achieve the same effect, aka that the player and iframe always render as large as possible, without exceeding max-width: 95vw and max-height: 72vh?